# Android, honeycomb animation ("Animators may only be run on Looper threads") error

Tags: android, animation, looper

I had a previous project in which I could generically use the ObjectAnimator class to animate any class like this

```
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(testShape, "translateX", 0f, 000f);
oa.setDuration(1000l);
oa.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
oa.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
oa.start();
```

...and that would run great, no issues. Now when i try to run the same setup i get

```
W/dalvikvm(19053): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400d1760)
E/AndroidRuntime(19053): FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread
E/AndroidRuntime(19053): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads
E/AndroidRuntime(19053):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:900)
E/AndroidRuntime(19053):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime(19053):    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:282)
E/AndroidRuntime(19053):    at com.processing.test.Run.setup(Run.java:43)
```

I have tried to add the Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop() in my draw loops but to no avail. Since I haven't had to use the Looper class at all previously though, this is an undesired approach.

Could this be a version issue with my underlying lib (processing-android in this case) or is it due to a change in Honeycomb from 3.0 to 3.1

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs for ObjectAnimator it doesn't appear that things changed: what you probably just need to do is make sure you are making the call from the UI thread: either make sure it is being called in an event handler method, use a Handler instance or do View.post() with a Runnable that actually runs the animation. Did you suddenly start invoking `start` from a different location?